# How to get the next ascii char in Prolog?

Tags: prolog

I want a predicate that works like this:

```
next_char(Curr, Next) :-
    Next is Curr + 1.
```

Which I could call like this:

```
next_char('D', X).
```

In which it would give me `X='E'`.

Unfortunately it doesn't seem like you can do this arithmetic on chars in Prolog. Cheers.

Comment: You can use the standard `char_code/2` predicate.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "ascii char"? Do you mean just the printable characters before 127?

Comment: Just the next char according to ascii. So if `Curr` were `!`, `Next` should be `"`. Disregard edge cases like if you flow over past 127, it will primarily be used for the alphabet.

Comment: With a bit of a work around I managed to do this:
string_codes(NewChar, [RowChar, ColChar])
Where the list in the second are is a list of ascii codes.
So NewChar = "AC" if 2nd arg is [65, 67]. But I'm keen for additional answers as this required using the actual numbers, not the chars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to cover the printable ASCII characters (32-127), you could simply make a "table" with all the characters and put it in the database. This is just a small example what it would look like:

```
% space is the first printable ASCII character
asciichar_succ(' ', '!').
asciichar_succ('!', '"').
% ...
asciichar_succ(a, b).
asciichar_succ(b, c).
% ...
asciichar_succ('}', '~').
```

One way to add this to the database would be to use compile-time term expansion, for example like this:

```
term_expansion(asciichar_succ(_, _), Chars) :-
        findall(asciichar_succ(C0, C1), asciichar_next(C0, C1), Chars).

asciichar_next(C0, C1) :-
        between(32, 125, Code0),
        succ(Code0, Code1),
        char_code(C0, Code0),
        char_code(C1, Code1).

asciichar_succ(_, _).
```

When I put this in a file `char_succ.pl`, and load this file from the SWI-Prolog top level, I get:

```
?- [char_succ].
true.

?- asciichar_succ(a, X).
X = b.

?- asciichar_succ(X, '"').
X = !.

?- listing(asciichar_succ/2).
asciichar_succ(' ', !).
asciichar_succ(!, '"').
asciichar_succ('"', #).
asciichar_succ(#, $).
asciichar_succ($, '%').
asciichar_succ('%', &).
% ...
asciichar_succ(?, @).
asciichar_succ(@, 'A').
asciichar_succ('A', 'B').
asciichar_succ('B', 'C').
% ...
asciichar_succ(y, z).
asciichar_succ(z, '{').
asciichar_succ('{', '|').
asciichar_succ('|', '}').
asciichar_succ('}', ~).

true.
```

Doing it like this has one very nice property: as long as at least one of the two arguments is ground, the predicate is deterministic and doesn't leave behind any choice points. In other words, `asciichar_succ/2` is a "true relation". You can definitely achieve the same end result with arithmetic at run time, but it will be a bit hairier to get right.

Comment: A name `asciichar_succ/2` might be preferable. Still, it is not clear why the successor of `'{'` would be of interest.

Comment: @false Altogether, there is some context missing. I also don't know why the successor of `!` being `"` is of much interest...

Comment: It is of interest just because that's the order in ascii. It's equally as important as `B` being the successor of `A`. Thank you very much though for a super comprehensive and robust predicate, marking as correct!

Comment: @DanielWesleyPorteous Glad it helped. My comment about importance was aimed at false, not you :)